# VBA external data source

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vbscript that creates a new sheet for each row in a separate worksheet, copies the template to the new sheet, and fills it out using 4 source documents.  These 4 source documents are separate workbooks, and to build the script I copied the 4 separate worksheets from 4 separate workbooks into the template workbook.  The source documents change, and I need a method of importing them each time this process is ran.  Template.xlsx is the main document I am working on filling out, but it gets copied to a new sheet for each row in Batch##Schedule.xlsx, which is sheet1. Sheet2 is VendorContactList, sheet3 is ProvisioningBatchA##.xlsx, and sheet4 is ProvisioningBatchB##.xlsx. Sheet1 determines how many times I copy the template to a new sheet, the other sheets are referenced using index/match functions to pull some data out like phone numbers, contact names, and various other pieces of information.  I use an ID to tie each row to the template and the template to the other source documents.

Working code to build template sheets (only works if I manually copy source data sheets into template workbook as sheet1-4).

````
Dim FinalRow As Long, i As Long
Dim FinalRowSheet4 As Long
Dim sheetNm As String
Dim AddressString As String
Dim shtD As Worksheet, sht1 As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim city As String
Dim state As String
Dim zip As String
Dim address As String

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sht1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    FinalRowSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    FinalRowSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    FinalRowSheet3 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    FinalRowSheet4 = Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To FinalRowSheet1  'initiates a loop
        'This loop will create a new sheet for each row in sheet 1 with the template stored on Ind Site Summary

        sheetNm = sht1.Cells(i, "A").Value
        'already a sheet for this?
        Set shtD = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set shtD = wb.Worksheets(sheetNm)
        On Error GoTo 0
        'no sheet already - create one
        If shtD Is Nothing Then
            Set shtD = wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
            shtD.Name = sheetNm
        End If
        'copy the values
        Sheets("Ind Site Summary").Cells.Copy Destination:=shtD.Range("A1")


        'Use rows in sheet1 to copy information into created sheets here
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "C").Copy Destination:=shtD.Range("B2").MergeArea
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "L").Copy Destination:=shtD.Range("E2").MergeArea
        shtD.Range("E2").Value = Range("E2").Value
        address = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Value
        city = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6).Value
        state = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Value
        AddressString = address & " " & city & " " & ", " & state
        Range("B3") = AddressString
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "J").Copy Destination:=shtD.Range("B10").MergeArea
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "K").Copy Destination:=shtD.Range("B11").MergeArea
    

'    Paste Formulas
    shtD.Range("E8").Formula2 = "=INDEX(Sheet3!$P$3:$P$" & FinalRowSheet3 & ",MATCH(E2,Sheet3!$B$3:$B$" & FinalRowSheet3 & ",0))" 'E8 - first part of vendor contact string
    shtD.Range("E9").Formula2 = "=INDEX(Sheet3!$Q$3:$Q$" & FinalRowSheet3 & ",MATCH(E2,Sheet3!$B$3:$B$" & FinalRowSheet3 & ",0))" 'E9 - second part of vendor contact string

'    Phone Numbers
'    shtD.Range("E15").Formula2 = "COUNTA(B18:B25)" 'E15 - count of lines in use
'    ""+ Backup LAN Data Connection"" E16
    shtD.Range("I18").Formula2 = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet4!$C$2:$C$" & FinalRowSheet4 & ",MATCH(1,($E$2=Sheet4!$A$2:$A$" & FinalRowSheet4 & ")*(A18=Sheet4!$G$2:$G$" & FinalRowSheet4 & "),0)),"""")" 'E18
    shtD.Range("J18").Formula2 = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet4!$H$2:$H$" & FinalRowSheet4 & ",MATCH(1,($E$2=Sheet4!$A$2:$A$" & FinalRowSheet4 & ")*(A18=Sheet4!$G$2:$G$" & FinalRowSheet4 & "),0)),"""")" 'E19
    'Fill Down
    shtD.Range("I18:I25").FillDown
    shtD.Range("J18:J26").FillDown


    Next i

    sht1.Activate

End Sub ```


Previous code I've used for importing source data (1 sheet), but this looks at named ranges to get the file and path.  I would prefer a solution that lets me use a file picker to update the source data sheets.   

``` Sub LoadData()
    'This subroutine will load data from text-formatted files without opening them.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks("Master.xlsm")
 
    Filename = Range("FileName").Value
    SheetName = Range("SheetName").Value
    Extension = Range("Extension").Value
    
    If Extension = ".csv" Then
        isCSV = True
    Else
        isCSV = False
    End If

    If (SheetExists(SheetName, wb) = False) Then
        Call createSheet(SheetName, wb)
    End If

    Sheets(SheetName).Select
    Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 1).Select

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables _
        .Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & Filename, Destination:=ActiveCell)
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = (Not (isCSV))
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = isCSV
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Item(ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Count).Delete
    wb.Sheets("Config").Activate
    
End Sub

Function SheetExists(ByVal shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    'This subroutine will test to see if a worksheet already exists within a workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet

     If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     On Error Resume Next
     Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
     On Error GoTo 0
     SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function

Sub createSheet(ByVal shtName As String, wb As Workbook)
    'This subroutine will create a sheet for the data to be imported to, if that sheet does not already exist.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With wb
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = shtName
    End With
End Sub ```
````

Comment: Have the user select the source documents? This can be done with [`FileDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.FileDialog)

Comment: My confusion with this method would be that the user would always need to pick 4 files in the same order or else it could all be thrown off.  How can I guarantee that the files always go into the correct destination regardless of order?  In my code above, I am using sheet1, sheet2, sheet3, & sheet4 as the source data sheets.

Comment: sheet1, sheet2, sheet3, & sheet4 and (presumably) work_sheets_. FileDialog is there to select one or more Work_books_ (you may need to get the user to select one workbook four times instead of selecting four workbooks once). I think you should provide an example of files you need selected to make things clearer.

Comment: So I have basically template.xlsx.  This is the main document I am working on filling out, but it gets copied to a new sheet for each row in Batch##Schedule.xlsx, which is sheet1.  Sheet2 is VendorContactList, sheet3 is ProvisioningBatchA##.xlsx, and sheet4 is ProvisioningBatchB##.xlsx.  Sheet1 determines how many times I copy the template to a new sheet, the other sheets are referenced using index/match functions to pull some data out like phone numbers, contact names, and various other pieces of information.  Is it still unclear?  I apologize for being unclear.

Comment: It's better to add info by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68562705/edit) not everyone will dig through comments on the off chance a critical piece of info is there

Comment: thanks, I edited the question.  I hope its clearer